# How can we upgrade old GCC 3.4 to GCC 4.1 on Fedora 3?

Tags: linux, fedora, gcc

How can we upgrade the old GCC from version 3.4 to 4.1(that is from GCC 3.4 to GCC 4.1 or above) on Fedora 3 (version is 2.6.10)?

More information: We are developing an application which will be running on Fedora 3, but the application needs some atomic built-ins,__sync_val_compare_and_swap, __sync_fetch_and_add, etc, which are only available on GCC 4.1 or above. SO I think we can either define them or upgrade gcc to new one on Fedora 3, but now we don't know both.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Why don't you just change the version of Fedora that includes the version of GCC compiler you need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much a bad idea. If you develop with a set of libraries that your target system doesn't have, your app most likely won't work when deployed. Having said that, your best bet is to find the oldest version of Fedora with the required version of GCC, grab the source package, and try to rebuild a binary RPM. Good luck.

Comment: We finally figure out both solutions. Wo choose to implement the assembly functions ourself. Thanks John.